# If statement with tolerance

Tags: lua

I have a Domoticz LUA script for a thermostat and I would like to implement a tolerance in the IF statement.

Current code is like:

```
if (current < target) then
            debuglog('Heating - Turning Physical Heater On: '.. physicalheater)
 else debuglog('Heating - Turning Physical Heater OFF: '.. physicalheater)
```

What I would like to achieve is something like:

```
if (current < target +-2 ) then
            debuglog('Heating - Turning Physical Heater On: '.. physicalheater)
 else debuglog('Heating - Turning Physical Heater OFF: '.. physicalheater)
```

Comment: If `c` is less than `t - 2`, then it must also be less than `t - 1`, `t`, `t + 1`... This doesn't make much sense to me. If you want to check if a number is smaller than a range of numbers, you just compare it with the smallest number in the range.

Comment: You want a [hysteresis](http://www.drheet.com/2013/10/10/what-is-hysteresis/).

Comment: `if current < target-2 then TURN_ON() elseif current > target+2 then TURN_OFF() end`